# Is it possible to pass an argument to a computed property that is used for class and style bindings?

Tags: vue.js, binding, computed-properties

I have an array of travelers (e.g. `[2,0,0]` => 2 adults, 0 teens, 0 childs) that I use to build my template

```
<div v-for="(person, i) in travelers" :key="i" class="uk-width-1-3@m">
    <div class="uk-card-body">
        <button
            class="uk-button uk-button-small uk-margin-right"
            @click="changeTravelers({index: i, value: travelers[i]-1})"
            :class="{
                 'uk-disabled uk-button-default': travelers[i] == 0 || (curOcc !== 1 && curOcc <= minOcc),
                 'uk-button-primary': travelers[i] > 0 && (curOcc > minOcc || curOcc >= minOcc && travelers[i] === 1 && travelers[i+1] !== 1 && travelers[i+2] !== 1 && travelers[i-1] !== 1 && travelers[i-2] !== 1)
             }"
        >-</button>
        <span>{{ travelers[i] }}</span>
        <button
            class="uk-button uk-button-small uk-margin-left"
            @click="changeTravelers({index: i, value: travelers[i]+1})"
            :class="{'uk-disabled uk-button-default': curOcc >= maxOcc, 'uk-button-primary': curOcc < maxOcc}"
        >+</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I guess it's bad practice to implement so much logic into the `template` and it look's really awkward. Instead I want to use **[class and style bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax) with an computed property**.

```
styleMinusButton() {
    return {
        'uk-disabled uk-button-default': this.travelers[i] == 0 || (curOcc !== 1 && curOcc <= minOcc),
        'uk-button-primary': travelers[i] > 0 && (curOcc > minOcc || curOcc >= minOcc && travelers[i] === 1 && travelers[i+1] !== 1 && travelers[i+2] !== 1 && travelers[i-1] !== 1 && travelers[i-2] !== 1)
    }
}
```

But how do I access the `i` of the `v-for`? Can I pass it as an argument? Or is there a different and better solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could return a factory function in the computed prop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need arguments then you want to write a *method*, not a *computed property*.

```vue
<button :class="styleMinusButton(i)">...</button>
```

```js
methods: {
  styleMinusButton(i) {
    const { travelers, curOcc, minOcc } = this
    return {
      'uk-disabled uk-button-default': travelers[i] == 0 || (curOcc !== 1 && curOcc <= minOcc),
      'uk-button-primary': travelers[i] > 0 && (curOcc > minOcc || curOcc >= minOcc && travelers[i] === 1 && travelers[i+1] !== 1 && travelers[i+2] !== 1 && travelers[i-1] !== 1 && travelers[i-2] !== 1)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks @Decade Moon!! I also never used destructuring with `this` before. Really good to know :D